# STM32 timer external clock update event

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32, dma

I need to read from some GPIO pins via DMA on every falling edge of another external signal using STM32F407. I set the clock signal as TIMER external clock (falling edge) and set the PSC value and ARR value as 0. I set the timer update event as DMA request.

Problem is that according to the formula `f = Fclock/((PSC+1)*(ARR+1))`, DMA is triggered on each falling edge according to the clock signal from the pin. But there is no Trigger occurs.

When I set the ARR value to 1, DMA is triggered 1 time on every 2 falling edges.

Here is my current configuration:

```
DMA2_Stream5->NDTR = 20;
DMA2_Stream5->M0AR = (uint32_t) &buffer[0];
DMA2_Stream5->PAR = (uint32_t) &GPIOB->IDR;           
DMA2_Stream5->CR = (6u << DMA_SxCR_CHSEL_Pos) |       // select channel 6, see DMA request mapping in the reference manual
           DMA_SxCR_MSIZE_1 |      // 0b10:memory data size 32 bit
           DMA_SxCR_PSIZE_1 |      // 0b10:peripheral data size 32 bit
           DMA_SxCR_MINC |         // memory increment
           DMA_SxCR_EN |           // enable channel
           DMA_SxCR_TCIE_Msk |     // Transfer complete interrupt enable
           0;
TIM1->DIER = TIM_DIER_UDE;          //Update DMA request enable
TIM1->SMCR |= 1 << 15;              //ETR is inverted,
TIM1->CR1 = TIM_CR1_CEN;            //TIM1 enable
```

How can I configure DMA to be triggered on each falling edge of the external signal?

Answer (score 2):

Which STM32? [EDIT] Okay I see STM32F407 in your post before @ceremcem edited it [/EDIT]

Next time, *read out* and post content of all relevant peripherals' registers (here, TIM and DMA/DMAMUX).

> ARR value as 0

If you set ARR=0, timer's counter does not run (i.e. does not change its value upon clocks and does not generate Update events), see description of TIMx_ARR register in RM.

Instead of using ETR and Update, connect the input signal to one of the timer's channels, set that channel as Input Capture, and trigger DMA from that channel.

JW

Comment: I deleted that information mistakenly, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: When I did research, I came across examples of TIMER IC mod usually frequency measurement. How is the GPIO->IDR reading process done with IC DMA request? Can you share any resources about this?

Comment: Input capture not only copies current state of TIMx_CNT into TIMx_CCRx, but also generates a signal which sets TIMx_SR.CCxIF - in the very same way as in your original solution CNT overflowing generates Update signal which sets TIMx_SR.UIF. So, with Input Capture, you enable DMA by setting respective TIMx_DIER.CCxDE; and then select appropriate DMA Stream for that signal according to requests mapping table in DMA chapter (e.g. if you'd use TIM1_CH1, you'd enable DMA by setting TIM1_DIER.CC1DE, and then use DMA2_Stream1 or DMA2_Stream3 set to Channel6, or DMA2_Stream6 set to Channel0.